# Gmail : Retrieve the mails from specific sender. API..?

Tags: api, gmail, mail-sender

I am stuck in the middle of a project and need help retrieving the mails only from a particular sender in Gmail.
Can anyone suggest some API to do so OR can share any script to get it from the server..??

It would be very Helpful. Thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 0):

just enable the IMAP, the gmail IMAP servers support server side search. Then take whatever IMAP library in language of your preference and download search results :)